# Weren't 2.5 tribes afraid that their families would be attacked?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, eretz-yisrael, mattos

The deal with Moses was that while all the men go conquer the land, the kids and families and cattle stay abroad.

Weren't they afraid that their cities: families and cattle and property would be attacked by hostile nations, like Amalek, Moabites, and others they didn't exterminate?

Comment: Josephus in Antiquities Of The Jews, Book IV:5 says that the land of Sihon was safely bounded by three rivers, the Jordan, Jabbok, and Arnon, making it like an island. He doesn't say anything similar about Og's territory, though.

Comment: I seem to recall some Medrash that says when the people who went with the Jews to Israel returned to where they left their family, they found their families engaged in a war.

Comment: Please delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

Bameedbar 32 17

> ואנחנו נחלץ חשים לפני בני ישראל עד אשר אם הביאנם אל מקומם וישב טפנו
>   בערי המבצר מפני ישבי הארץ

...We will be vanguard for Israelis util we will bring them to their land, and our children will sit at the fortified cities, protected from hostiles
Well, a fort is usless without some garrison, so they obviously they left some men behind to guard the cites.

Comment: You start well and then end "* they obviously they left some men"*. That's the "obviously" I'm looking for.

Comment: Your answer is perfect for a comment, I had similar speculations. I'm interested in some deeper proofs. The environment was too hostile to skip such explanations.

Comment: You looking for a proof that people used common sense?

Comment: This site does not accept common sense as an answer it requires proofs. You might want to develop your idea further, linking it to other similar stories or speculating why those tribes specifically.